# How to solve "ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed" issue while running cpp in CLion?

Tags: c++, clion

Today I was going to run a simple code in CLion. But suddenly this error occurs. I was coding normally like before. did not change or modify any other options in CLion.

This was the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char x;
    x = 'S';
    cout << x; 
    return 0;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Dont post images, but the error message itself as text. And subcommand failed means, that some part of the compilation failed, it is not the error message that is the real problem there must be another one.

Comment: My guess judging by the real compiler error ("multiple definition of main") and the names of the files, is that you have two mains: one in your exe and one in your unit tests, and you're trying to compile them together.  This is a problem with your CMakeLists.txt.